# Error recognising password; importing OSM to PostGIS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

When selecting OSM Tools (Import into PostGIS) , attching my .osm file in the Input option, selecting my OSM Database, and then clicking run, I am prompted to enter a password for connection.

```
"Enter password for connection (or leave blank) "osm":"
```

When either leaving blank, making up a password, or using my Postgres password I get this error.

```
Password:
Connection to database failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm"
Finshed!
```

I not sure what I am doing wrong. From what I have read it should authenticate.

Thanks for any time you have.

Comment: Do you have a user with the name osm?

Comment: No I don't think I do. Well I havn't created a user. And what ever password I put in it comes back with an error. For example when putting in a password of "open" it returns: Password:

Connection to database failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "open"
Finished!